# Trouble issues When I run dev Client - ConnectDB is not a function

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux

I have an issue, when i run dev client I got an error which is: connectDB is not functions.
I tried to fix it with many solutions suggested but i couldn't fix the bug.

There is the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA6ox.png) of my code.

Below the code

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {connectDB} =async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true });

        console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Below
the code of server file

```
 const express = require('express')
//const colors = require('colors')
const dotenv  = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
const connectDB = require('./config/db')


const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

connectDB()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false}))

app.use('/api/tasks', require('./routes/taskRoutes'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))

app.use(errorHandler)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

After that i I added this script to package.json :
[Dev script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcsMA.png)

Bellow the error message

```
 C:\Users\hp\Documents\DjamilaWorld\Projects\tasks-app\backend\server.js:11
[0] connectDB()
[0] ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: connectDB is not a function
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\DjamilaWorld\Projects\tasks-app\backend\server.js:11:1)
[0]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
[0]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
[0]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
[0]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] (node:16544) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[1] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[1] (node:16544) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1]
[1] You can now view frontend in the browser.
[1]
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.197.1:3000
[1]
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use npm run build.
[1]
[1] webpack compiled successfully
Terminer le programme de commandes (O/N) ? [1] ^C^CTerminer le programme de commandes (O/N)�? ^CTerminer le programme de commandes 
(O/N)�? npm run client exited with code 1
[0] npm run server exited with code 1
```

Comment: Try removing parenthesis around `connectDB` in your **db.js**.

Comment: The issue is fixed by removing parenthesis. Thanks!